# Thinking sphinx put indexes on swap device

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am using thinking sphinx  version 2.0.10 in rails for full text search and I am dealing with millions of record in Database. it take huge time to return result. so is there any way to keep the indexes on swap device. so it will work faster.

Thank You for Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking Sphinx configures Sphinx to store attributes in memory - but as far as I know there's no such setting that applies to field data. Sphinx index files can be stored on any disk you like though, instead of just `RAILS_ROOT/db/sphinx/RAILS_ENV` - this is configured using the `searchd_file_path` setting in `config/sphinx.yml`.

Perhaps you could elaborate on how you're using Sphinx and Thinking Sphinx - what kinds of queries you're running that are slow, and what the relevant index structures look like. There may be other ways of improving the speed of this.